# How can I call logger on model

Tags: model

I want to call logger by `objectManager` on **Model** 
But I don't know how to call logger object.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$logger = $objectManager->get('which object');
```

Comment: Psr\Log\LoggerInterface

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to instantiate this Interface:

"Psr\Log\LoggerInterface"

You should however not use object manager but instead add it to your current class using dependency injection:

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
class Example {

    private $_logger;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface  and see results in var/log/debug.log

```
class Example{
protected $_logger;
public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, //log injection
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    parent::__construct($data);
}
public function someExampleMethod() {
    /*
    some logic of method
    */
    //accessing to logger instance and calling log method
    $this->_logger->log('some text or variable');
    /// for array use this
   // $this->_logger->log(100,print_r($layout,true));
}
```